# Use ng2-toastr in a service

Tags: angular, typescript

**Scenario:** I need to use `ng2-toaster` to display messages in all the components. Instead of writing the same toaster in every components. I need to write a component in a global service once and all the components make use of it. But I couldn't make it work. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

**Here's my code:**

**global.service.ts**

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
'''
constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager) { }
...
showSuccess() {
  this.toastr.success('Called from Global service', 'Success!', {toastLife: 3000});
}
```

**some.component.ts**

```
import { GlobalService } from './services';
...
ngInit(){
   this.globalService.showSuccess()
}
```

**Error:**

this is the error i'm getting.

```
Error: Application root component cannot be found. Try accessing application reference in the later life cycle of angular app.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Angular v2.2.x you need to add below in your Root component of your app :

// AppComponent.ts (Root component of your app)

```
constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager, vRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vRef);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what i need.